# java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException trying to make request to an API

Tags: java, spring

Hi I'm new in prgramming and English is not my native language so I apologize for the mistakes.

I'm getting the below exception when trying to make a http request to an API

```
[ERROR   ] SRVE0777E: Exception thrown by application class 'org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest:973'
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:973)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1240)
    at [internal classes]
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException
    at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.validateConstructorArguments(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.<init>(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:53)
    at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.make(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeParameterizedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:105)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository.getSuperInterfaces(ClassRepository.java:100)
    at java.lang.Class.getGenericInterfaces(Class.java:814)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.getAllContractsFromInterfaces(ReflectionHelper.java:366)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.getAdvertisedTypesFromClass(ReflectionHelper.java:351)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.getAdvertisedTypesFromObject(ReflectionHelper.java:391)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.BuilderHelper.createConstantDescriptor(BuilderHelper.java:392)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBindingBuilder$InstanceBasedBindingBuilder.complete(AbstractBindingBuilder.java:286)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder.resetBuilder(AbstractBinder.java:179)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder.complete(AbstractBinder.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder.bind(AbstractBinder.java:173)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig$State.initRuntime(ClientConfig.java:406)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig$State.access$000(ClientConfig.java:86)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig$State$3.get(ClientConfig.java:118)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig$State$3.get(ClientConfig.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.collection.Values$LazyValueImpl.get(Values.java:322)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig.getRuntime(ClientConfig.java:721)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.getConfiguration(ClientRequest.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.validateHttpMethodAndEntity(JerseyInvocation.java:126)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.<init>(JerseyInvocation.java:98)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.<init>(JerseyInvocation.java:91)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:408)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.get(JerseyInvocation.java:308)
    at br.com.MyLOL.home.LOLClient.getSummonerInfo(LOLClient.java:23)
    at br.com.MyLOL.summoner.SummonerService.getSummonerInfo(SummonerService.java:16)
    at br.com.MyLOL.home.HomeController.result(HomeController.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    ... 6 more

[ERROR   ] SRVE0315E: An execption occurred: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppErrorReport: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed&#59; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:973)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1240)
    at [internal classes]
```

this is maven pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>MyLOL</groupId>
  <artifactId>MyLOL</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <repositories>

 </repositories>

  <dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.14</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
```

method trowing the exception

```
public Summoner  getSummonerInfo(Summoner summoner) {
    javax.ws.rs.client.Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    WebTarget target = client.target("http://" + summoner.getSummonerRegion()+".api.pvp.net");
    String summonerInfo = target.path("api/lol/"+ summoner.getSummonerRegion() +"/v1.4/summoner/by-name/" + summoner.getSummonerName() + "?api_key=11111111111").request().get(String.class);
    System.out.println(summonerInfo);
    return new Summoner();
}
```

}

Idk what else would be relevant for someome to help find a solution so please ask me for anything else you may need

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, whatever that String you try to get is, its not a String. Maybe that API you are using (I didn't look into that) tries constructing that String in an impossible manner.